# How to test if term is correlated to news category

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, experiment-design

Suppose we have a corpus of news articles that contain a term. We also have the category for each article, which ranges from Sports to Politics, etc. What statistical approach would we take to determine if the term is correlated to a specific category? The way I'm looking at it is this could be a pairwise correlation analysis, but I'm struggling to set up the basis for the test—do I have enough variables? Do I need more data to be able to test correlations, e.g. articles that do not contain the term? Can I bring years into the picture somehow?

Comment: Do you have one binary variable of whether or not the article contains "sassafras" and one categorical variable of the article topic? And what do you mean about "correlated to a specific category"?

Comment: Yes, I have these two variables currently. I also have the date. I'm thinking I could break it down into date chunks or an overall dateless chunk, so I'm not too concerned about the date right now.

Comment: What do you mean about "correlated to a specific category"?

Comment: We want to prove if the term appears more often in articles from a certain category (or categories), compared to other categories. We can show this by eyeballing a bar graph, but we need a statistical test.

Comment: It sounds like a chi-squared test would be a start. This would test if your news topics have unequal proportions of "sassafras" but would not do pairwise comparisons. Would those matter to you?